# Remove certain characters from the data to make it a valid json

Tags: php, json, api

Having a JSON response from an API which has some strange output that doesn't let me to parse. Here is the response :

```
2: 40822: 42["contest", {
    "start_time": 1545638460000,
    "show_time": 1545638400000,
    "start_after": 0,
    "show_time_after": 0,
    "uid": "YDDZZKJWPR",
    "stream_start_at": -1,
    "stream_start_after": 0,
    "user_status": "10"
}] 631: 42["choiceq", {
    "uid": "YDDZZKJWPR",
    "text": "Select a color of your choice !",
    "question_type": "normal-question",
"options": [{
    "uid": "FLEL6CL9MS",
    "text": "Blue",
    "rank": 2
}, {
    "uid": "HXZRYDTRP9",
    "text": "Green",
    "rank": 1
}, {
    "uid": "VGC3URSDU1",
    "text": "Red",
    "rank": 0
}],
"server_time": 1545638500614,
"question_card_data": {
    "header_text": null,
    "band_color": null
},
"user_status": "10",
"user_answer": "VGC3URSDU1"
}]
```

Here are two sets of characters which make it an invalid JSON data - `2: 40822: 42` and `631: 42`. These 2 sets of data dynamically change in every request to the API. Normal parsing the data is not helping.
I am using PHP to parse the file like `contest['start_time']` but it returning value error.
How can I parse this JSON response or escape these two sets of data?

Comment: You will need to post the current code you have to demonstrate what you have tried and what problems you have with your current working code. It's not even clear what language you are working in.

Comment: I am using PHP to parse the json.

Comment: can you add your current code to the question?

Comment: Added the code that I am using to parse.

Comment: I'd recommend reading [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to ask on stack overflow - you are currently asking people to write the code for you.

Comment: Do you have any influence on that API, or is it some external service you cannot fix? Is there another working service that could replace the failing API?

Comment: No, I do not have any control over the API. And I need this particular API to get this response.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the API is trying to return two different sets of data. You can extract them by using `preg_split`:

```
$data = 'put your original JSON data here';
$pattern = '/\s?\d+:\s\d+(:\s\d+)?/';
$data = preg_split($pattern, trim($data));
$contest = json_decode($data[1], true);
$choiceq = json_decode($data[2], true);
```

`preg_split` will do two things in the example above: extract two separate JSON strings from your invalid JSON data and remove the wrong characters. It uses a regular expression to find all strings matching a pattern you posted (i.e. numbers separated by a colon and a space) and it splits the original string.

Comment: Problem is, the regex could in theory appear inside a string in the data. Worst case: In a user generated message - might make the whole thing hackable in the end.

Comment: Yes this is very much working. Thank you for the answer.